# how to overcome conflict between 2 network cards - virtualbox ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I am running ubuntu 10.4.04 LTS as guest in virtualbox on OSX Yosemite.

Unfortunatelly I seem to have the network configured wrong I followed this tutorials http://coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/VirtualBox-Configuring-Static-IPs-for-VMs http://archive.gregk.me/2010/working-on-vm-server-while-offline/

There are two network cards configured. eth0 to have static ip adress that is internal, and eth7 to have internet access inside ubunutu.

Sometimes it workes, sometimes not. DNS works, but I can not get any connection. Ping failes. I narrowed it down and found that if I ifdown eth0 the internet becomes reachable again.

Here is my setup. Thank you for any help:

configuration:

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0 eth0:0 eth0:1 eth7
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.56.114
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.56.0
    broadcast 192.168.56.255
    gateway 192.168.56.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.56.1

    iface eth0:0 inet static
      address 192.168.56.115
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.56.1


    iface eth0:1 inet static
      address 192.168.56.116
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 192.168.56.0
    broadcast 192.168.56.255


    iface eth7 inet dhcp
```

This is what ifconfig -a tells me:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a6:53:7b  
      inet addr:192.168.56.114  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea6:537b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5079240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1673378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5810178346 (5.8 GB)  TX bytes:1191816042 (1.1 GB)


    eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a6:53:7b  
              inet addr:192.168.56.115  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

    eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a6:53:7b  
              inet addr:192.168.56.116  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

    eth7      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:03:65:17  
              inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe03:6517/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:657625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:59635 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:951459365 (951.4 MB)  TX bytes:5054133 (5.0 MB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:91728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:91728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:34336299 (34.3 MB)  TX bytes:34336299 (34.3 MB)

    tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
              inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
              UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

[image: routing table]
[image: routing table after fix]

Comment: What does your routing table look like? `netstat -rn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling your machine that *both* interfaces should be handling traffic to the rest of the world. You see this in the last two lines of your routing table.

If I've understood you correctly, it's the interface that gets its information from DHCP that's connected to the internet, and the other one is only connected to 192.168.56.0/24. If this is correct, you simply need to remove the `gateway` line from your configuration. The term `gateway` means just that - that it's the way to the rest of the world. By removing it, you are saying that there's no way to use that network to go on to the internet, which will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Jenny! That fixed the problem. I have added the routing table to the question after fixing issue. Seems to be OK now.